# How to change button text colour in a Toolbar?

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, colors, toolbar

Is it possible to change the colour of `Button` text, where the button exists in a Toolbar?

I tried the following in `app.xaml`

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Toolbar}"> <!-- this changes the background colour -->
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="AliceBlue"/> <!-- works -->
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/> <!-- doesn't work -->
</Style>
```

and I've tried

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}"> <!-- this changes both colours -->
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="AliceBlue"/> <!-- works -->
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/> <!-- work -->
</Style>
```

The toolbar is defined as:

```
<ToolBarTray Background="White" Width="Auto">
    <ToolBar UseLayoutRounding="True" >
        <Button Content="Options"  Name="btnOptionsSettings" Click="btnOptionsSettings_Click" ></Button>
        <Button Content="Timer"    Name="btnTimerSettings" Click="btnTimerSettings_Click" ></Button>
        <Button Content="Blocks"   Name="btnBlocks" Click="btnBlocks_Click" ></Butto

    </ToolBar>
</ToolBarTray>
```

Comment: I found an answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701263/c-sharp-wpf-how-to-modify-the-toolbar-buttonstylekey-style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this by calling external style sheet